# Does boto3.session need to tie to Flask application context?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, boto3

According to [Boto3 Doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/session.html#multithreading-or-multiprocessing-with-sessions), *Session* objects are not thread safe. My understanding is that we therefore need to tie boto3 session to application context if we use boto3 in a Flask application. I thought there should be a mature solution for that since both boto3 and Flask are so widely used. However, I find none (except for the pip package [flask-boto3](https://github.com/Ketouem/flask-boto3/blob/master/flask_boto3/__init__.py) which is awfully outdated and doesn't support Flask 1.x). Meanwhile, I find a lot of examples online (eg: [this example](https://rajrajhans.com/2020/06/2-ways-to-upload-files-to-s3-in-flask/)) that simply use *boto3* directly in a view function without creating a new session, suggesting sharing one session is not an issue. I am confused. I guess I must misunderstand something.  What's the correct way of using boto3 in a Flask application? Thanks!